# Why can't I return a string from an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I am trying to read an online txt file from my Dropbox and put its content into a string with an Asynctask but I can't manage to return my string.

My Code:

```
new LongOperation().execute("");
}
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String path ="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29289946/PCGAMEDONWLOADER/Slots/All%20Games/Rows_available/link2.txt";
        URL u = null;
        try {
            u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String album = bo.toString();


                    try {
                        bo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return album;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingtext);
        txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
}
```

Now eclipse underlines "album" next to return, so I can't use it in further operations.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put this `String album = ""` after `URL u = null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you run the UI thread to assign the data to a string...you can use it in side your thread.

Simply do in your `doInBackground` method()like:

```
 bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.
 String album = bo.toString();
 return album;
```

And here your main problem is you define your String variable locally inside runInMainThread() method. Then how you access it out of its surrounding area. If you don't want to change your program then just define the String globally like:

```
 public String doInBackGround()String...params){
 String album = "";
 .....
 ....
```

And asign the value anywhere... like `album=bo.toString();`   and return ....

Answer (score 1):

You initialized `album` in this function:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String album = bo.toString();


                try {
                    bo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

So it is only available in this scope. You could have seen this by checking what error Eclipse actually shows you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you declare your album String in your `runOnUiThread`, so it will not be known outside of it. Try to declare it in your `onPostExecute` like follow:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String path ="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29289946/PCGAMEDONWLOADER/Slots/All%20Games/Rows_available/link2.txt";
        URL u = null;
//Declare it here as final
final String album=null;
        try {
            u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   album = bo.toString();


                    try {
                        bo.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return album;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingtext);
        txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```